# VSCODE starting instead of script

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, npx

I freshly installed nodejs on a new notebook (together with chocolately).
The I installed requirejs (with npn install -g) requirejs

Whenever I try to run requirejs (r.js), vscode opens and displays the script instead of running it.

How do I correct thsi?

Comment: How are you trying to run the .js file?
If you are double clicking it, it's just that you defined visual code for theses types of files and it is the default executed program. Try changing the default application (right click -> properties -> open with -> change).

Comment: Simply running on the command line
npx r.js
NB: It opens a bash script in vscode